# Angular | Navigate to Specific Page After Azure Authentication

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, msal-angular

Details about Framework and packages.

1. Web Application: Angular 7
2. microsoft-adal-angular6": "^1.3.0"
3. "msal": "1.4.14"

Multiple Pages:

1. Home
2. History

User want to navigate from Home page to History page.  Then history page open in new tab. Normally its working fine.

[image]

But if token expire then user navigate from Home Page to History page then re-authenticate and navigate to home page instead of History page.

[image]

Now, the question is, if its possible to navigate to history page after authentication is performed?